# Format Data as Hexadecimal String to Increase MD5 Hash Computation in C

Tags: c, optimization

I wrote a piece of C code and asked someone on [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192306/optimizing-md5-openssl-implementation-in-c-for-precomputed-hash/192326#192326) to optimized it for me. However, I didn't really understand his implementation of the optimization.

His solutions were:

1. Write a custom function for converting the MD5 hash to a hex string.
2. Call `printf` for the entire string instead of each single byte so reduce the number of function calls.

Most of the code remain the same except for some minor changes. However, he wrote a custom function outside the main function which is really the key to the optimization. Unfortunately, I didn't really get it. May someone explain the first part of the code for me in the context of the rest of the program?

In the comment it says that `// Format the data as a hexadecimal string. The buffer must have space for 2 * length + 1 characters.` But why does the buffer must have the space for 2 times the length plus 1 character?

**The first part of the code outside the main function:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <openssl/md5.h>

    // Format the data as a hexadecimal string. The buffer must have
    // space for `2 * length + 1` characters.
    const char *hexString(unsigned char *data, size_t length, char *buffer) {
        const char *hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";
        char *dest = buffer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            *dest++ = hexDigits[data[i] >> 4];
            *dest++ = hexDigits[data[i] & 0x0F];
        }
        *dest = 0;
        return buffer;
    }
```

---

**The rest of the code:**

```
int main(void) {
                FILE *infile = fopen("infile", "r");
                if (infile == NULL) {
                    perror("Cannot open input file");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                FILE *outfile = fopen("cout3","w");
                if (outfile == NULL) {
                    perror("Cannot open output file");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                // Read file line-by-line
                char *line = NULL;
                size_t linecap = 0;
                ssize_t lineLength;
                while ((lineLength = getline(&line, &linecap, infile)) != -1) {
                    if (lineLength > 0 && line[lineLength - 1] == '\n') {
                        // Remove newline character
                        lineLength -= 1;
                        line[lineLength] = 0;
                    }

                    // Compute MD5 hash
                    unsigned char md5hash[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
                    MD5((unsigned char*)line, lineLength, md5hash);

                    // Print hash as hex string
                    char hexBuffer[2 * MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1];
                    fputs(hexString(md5hash, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, hexBuffer), outfile);
                    fputc('\n', outfile);
                }
                free(line);

                // Close output files
                fclose(infile);
                fclose(outfile);
            }
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: "However, I didn't really understand his implementation of the optimization." --> Then why accept the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/192326/29485)?

Comment: @chux I understand the implementation in a general sense (as stated in his comments), and it does cut the program's execution time by a factor of 6 on my side. However, the nitty-gritty of how the function works is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the custom function you mentioned is to split one byte to two byte, which is the printable hex view of the byte, so the buffer needs to be 2 * length, since the output is a string, and it needs an extra byte at the end of the buffer for the character '\0'.

Comment: How about the part under the for loop? There are hex representation of a byte (upper and lower part), that's all I can get.